# Windows/Batch/CLI | why if exists/else statements don't work with variables?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

```
set format1=txt
set format2=pdf

for %%h in ('dir /B *.%format1%') do ( 
    if exists %%h (
        for %%i in (*.%format2%) do ( 
            copy "%%i" "pdf\%%i"
        )
    )
    else (
        copy "%%h" "txt\%%h"
    )
)
```

So basically, if file of a format exists do this and if not, do else.

If I toggle .bat file, cmd window just blinks even with `pause` at the end.

Comment: Open a cmd window, drag the batch file in and run it, then you'll see any errors. Also, the if exist is not necessary, you are looping over the files already found.

Comment: After having corrected the syntax error pointed out in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43226133), the `else` clause is never giong to be executed, because `for %%h` returns existing files only; if you provided a clear description of what the code is intended to do, it would be much easier to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `else` is put on the beginning of the line it will be not part of `if` command and that line will be ignored or error message will be printed .It needs closing bracket. And in the outer for you need either to use `for /f` to parse a command output or a plain `for`. And you should use `if exist` instead of `if exists`

Try like this:

```
set format1=txt
set format2=pdf

for %%h in (*.%format1%) do ( 
    if exist "%%h" (
        for %%i in (*.%format2%) do ( 
            copy "%%i" "pdf\%%i"
        )
    ) else (
        copy "%%h" "txt\%%h"
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Didn't change much tho. Still not working.

Comment: oh i see the exists was a typo too?

Comment: The `if exist` is not necessary, since the `for %%f in (*.%format%)` will loop through all *existing* files. So the `else` part will never be run.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - I was just following the OP's logic and pointed his syntax errors.